# Python: Looping Through Multiple lists and Appending to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists and using a range function i need to go through the list and print out a list of 10 tuples.

```
list_1=[3,43,34,34,32,43,54,45,45]
list_2=[3,43,34,34,2,34,23,23,43]

for indenti in range(10):
   for list1 in list_1:
       for list2 in list_2:
             temp = (identi,[list1,list2])
             table.append(temp)
print(table)
```

The above function is supposed to print a list of tuples like the following. But when I print the table the last tuple is printed `[(9, [41.74490743920966, 46.86562115881449, 0])]`

```
[(0, [41.74490743920966, 46.86562115881449, 0])]
[(1, [41.74490743920966, 46.86562115881449, 0])]
[(2, [41.74490743920966, 46.86562115881449, 0])]
[(3, [41.74490743920966, 46.86562115881449, 0])]
```

Can someone point to me what I am missing or doing wrong that my code only prints out the last tuple insted of all the tuples in a list like the example above.

Comment: `[(9, [41.74490743920966, 46.86562115881449, 0])]` -- what's wrong with this line? It matches the other 4 examples...

Comment: that's an example its supposed to be different number for each identi, but only the last tuple in the sequence it printed.

Comment: It's still unclear what your exact problem is - what's wrong with that output - what were you expecting?. Please could you **provide expected outputs** (as you were [asked last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143677/python-appending-multiple-values-to-a-list))

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't even run. (table not defined, mispelling of identi/indenti. If those are corrected then it correct produces a table, though it contains many duplicates. Is that the problem?

Comment: `list(zip(range(10), list_1, list_2))`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your desired behavior:

```
>>> list_1=[3,43,34,34,32,43,54,45,45]
>>> list_2=[3,43,34,34,2,34,23,23,43]
>>> [(i, [list_1[i],list_2[i]]) for i in range(len(list_1))]
```

Output

```
[(0, [3, 3]), (1, [43, 43]), (2, [34, 34]), (3, [34, 34]), (4, [32, 2]), (5, [43, 34]), (6, [54, 23]), (7, [45, 23]), (8, [45, 43])]
```

Formatted, that result is

```
[(0, [3, 3]),
 (1, [43, 43]),
 (2, [34, 34]),
 (3, [34, 34]),
 (4, [32, 2]),
 (5, [43, 34]),
 (6, [54, 23]),
 (7, [45, 23]),
 (8, [45, 43])]
```

Comment: I would change it to `l1, l2 in zip(list_1, list_2)` or `range(min([len(list_1), len(list_2)]))` to avoid index error